# Displaying attributes upon their polygons within ArcMap legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.2, legend

Within my ArcMap project (10.2.2) I've got a polygon feature class showing soil types. They are styled using a representation and additionally show the number of the soil type from my attribute table.
This is what the legend looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to design the legend so the numbers are laid upon the colored polygons as shown in the following picture?

Preferably without converting to graphics or any other manual rework.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have managed this earlier by following this workflow:

1. Double-click the Legend in the Layout.
2. Legend Properties > Items tab.
3. Select the layer in the list and click the Style button.
4. Click the Properties button.
5. Go to the General tab and click Label Symbol.
6. Click the Edit Symbol button.
7. Then use the X and Y offset values to move the labels to the left - for instance, for X -30.

[image]

This basically moves the label to the left so it ends up being shown on top of the rectangles.

Answer (score 6):

You need to workaround this using the following:

1. Duplicate the original legend to a have a copy of it.
2. Double click the original legend go to items -> double click the target layer -> General -> Appearance make sure all labels are unchecked. If you want to show the Layer label of the original legend, you need to do the same for the copied one.
3. Double Click the copied legend go to items -> double click the target layer (the copy) -> Arrangement and choose the second option which starts with label -> General -> Under Appearance check Show Labels.
4. Go to layout tab and set the width and height of Symbol to 0.001 as shown below

[image]

5. You may need to adjust the "Vertical patch gap"
6. Select both the original and copied legends and align center and top, then you will have what you are looking for. Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Are you able to post the image that will be produced when following your workflow? It doesn't work for me as I don't get any symbols shown at all.

Comment: I added an image of the final output.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. You create a copy of the legend with no symbols showing, so you have two legends - one shows the labels only (with no symbols) and another one only the symbols.

Comment: Yes, it's true.